# Exclude dot-files from the find-file Completion List

Tags: completion, find-file

When I run the `find-file` command and hit the tab key twice without giving anything, I get the `Completion List` of my, for instance, home directory. By default it lists everything inside, including the hidden files and directories ("dot-files").

Is it possible to exclude the dot-files in this case? But additionally, when I start typing `.` and then hit the tab twice, I would like to see the all or matched dot-files.

Comment: This isn't really helpful, because I don't know why does it work like that, but I know that Emacs doesn't autocmplete `.git` directory for me. (I'm not sure if that's due to IDO or Magit, but that would be a direction I'd look in first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731634/dont-show-uninteresting-files-in-emacs-completion-window).  This works for emacs 24.3.1, at least.

I put the following in my .emacs file:

```
; Don't show dot files in the completion...                               
(require 'cl-lib) ; Needed for cl-remove-if-not                                        

; Define string-suffix-p.                                                       
(defun string-suffix-p (str1 str2 &optional ignore-case)
  (let ((begin2 (- (length str2) (length str1))) (end2 (length str2)))
    (when (< begin2 0) (setq begin2 0))
    (eq t (compare-strings str1 nil nil str2 begin2 end2 ignore-case))))

; Modify to return true for files you're interested in.                         
(defun my-file-match (str)
  (and (not (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (x) (string-suffix-p x str))
                               completion-ignored-extensions))
       (not (string-prefix-p "." str))))

; Add the advice after completion.                                              
(defadvice completion-file-name-table (after ignoring-backups-f-n-completion
                                             activate)
  (if (and (listp ad-return-value) (stringp (car ad-return-value))
           (cdr ad-return-value))
      (let ((newlis (cl-remove-if-not 'my-file-match ad-return-value)))
        ; If there are no qualifiers, list everything.                          
        (if (and (listp newlis) (cdr newlis))
            (setq ad-return-value newlis)))))
```

Comment: You might consider switching to `cl-lib`, the successor to `cl`, and using `cl-remove-if-not`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `completion-file-name-table` is called with three arguments.  The first one is the string to be completed, and the second one is a predicate with which it is expected to filter possible matches.

We can put an advice around `completion-file-name-table` that calls the function with the original arguments unchanged when the first argument starts with a dot (so we have auto-completion when we actually want to open a dot-file), but that calls `completion-file-name-table` with a dot-file-excluding predicate when the first argument does not start with a dot.

```
(defun completion-f-n-table-ignoring-dot-prefix (fun str pred flag)
  "Call `completion-file-name-table' with a predicate that
ignores matches starting with a dot, unless STR starts with a
dot."
  (funcall fun str
           (cond ((string-prefix-p "." (file-name-nondirectory str))
                  pred)
                 ((not pred)
                  (lambda (str)
                    (not (string-prefix-p "." str))))
                 (t
                  (lambda (str)
                    (and (not (string-prefix-p "." str))
                         (funcall pred str)))))
           flag))

(advice-add 'completion-file-name-table :around
            'completion-f-n-table-ignoring-dot-prefix)
```

To restore the standard behaviour, remove the advice

```
(advice-remove 'completion-file-name-table
               'completion-f-n-table-ignoring-dot-prefix)
```